# Restsharp request parameter syntax issue

Tags: c#, django-rest-framework, restsharp

this is the example of request data

```
{
    "delivery_needed": "false",
    "merchant_id": "201", 
    "merchant_order_id": "123456",
    "amount_cents": "25000",
    "currency": "USD", 
    "items": [],
    "shipping_data": { 
        "name": "test_user", 
        "street": "sample street", 
        "city": "cairo", 
     }
}
```

I wrote the c# code but it seems there is an error with the syntax of the shipping data, and items.

this is the error I got

> {\"shipping_data\":{\"non_field_errors\":[\"Invalid data. Expected a
>   dictionary, but got str.\"]},\"items\":[\"Expected a list of items but
>   got type \\"str\\".\"]}

This is the c# code I wrote, I am confused with the syntax

```
var client = new RestClient("url");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("application/json", request.AddJsonBody(new { delivery_needed = "false", merchant_id = "201", merchant_order_id = "123456", amount_cents = "25000", currency = "USD", items = "[]", shipping_data = "{ ",  name = "test_user", street = "sample street", city = "Cairo"}), ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You currently construct the body of the request with malformed data.

You currently have `...shipping_data = "{ ",...` which is just a string as the error indicated when it was expecting a proper object model or key/value pair (dictionary).

`items` according to the error message is also not provided properly. it expects an array but it provided with again a string `"[]"`

You need to build the model properly

```
var model = new {
    delivery_needed = "false",
    merchant_id = "201",
    merchant_order_id = "123456",
    amount_cents = "25000",
    currency = "USD",
    items = new object[0], //<--This needs to be an array
    shipping_data = new {  //<--This needs to be a proper object
        name = "test_user",
        street = "sample street",
        city = "Cairo"
    }
};
var client = new RestClient("url");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
request.AddJsonBody(model); //<-- this will serialize and add the model as a JSON body.
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Note the construction of the model to be parsed as the body of the request. Look at how closely it resembles the example in the OP